# "Class is a collection of objects".is it right or wrong definition?

Tags: java, .net

In some java and .net books i have read the defination of class as:

> Class is a collection of objects.

Is not it a bit wrong definition?as we know class is used to enforse abstraction.
its like a datatype to create objects of its own type(i.e. the particular class types).

the other definition of class(which i think is more appropriate):

> A class--the basic building block of an object-oriented language such
>   as Java--is a template that describes the data and behavior associated
>   with instances of that class. When you instantiate a class you create
>   an object that looks and feels like other instances of the same class.
>   The data associated with a class or object is stored in variables; the
>   behavior associated with a class or object is implemented with
>   methods. Methods are similar to the functions or procedures in
>   procedural languages such as C.

so my question is both the above definition of class is diffrent or same?

Comment: I would say `Class is a collection of an object properties.

`

Comment: No. Class is what defines an object.

Comment: And collection of behaviors (methods). =)

Comment: I would say class is a blueprint of object....

Comment: Class can have collection of objects.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ i disagree,what if the class is not yet used for creating an object.?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch ya i think the same,but sometimes different definition in books confuses people.

Comment: You could have an empty class

Comment: @user2623213 While in class; use your teacher's definition.

Comment: @user2623213 No issues, If you did'nt get it. Follow Elliott :D

Comment: You can ask this question [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
When asked why is it called a class, I replied because it is a place where we teach
objects how to do things 

-- Rich Pattis
```

Let us not use the concept of class to define objects. Lets use the concept of objects to know what a class is.

**The primary thinking behind OOP is that it should be able to model real world entities**. By real world entities I mean solid, living, non-living concrete stuff that people feel and touch and would like to use their properties and behaviours in a the digital world.

There are objects like Porsche Carrera, Aston Martin, Lamborghini --- > Well these are cars. All these 3 are collection of cars.

Orange, Apple, Banana --> Collection of fruits

Spinach, Carrot, Lettuce --> Collection of vegetables

**To model these entities in a digital world, we use the concept of a class**. A class is used to define the behaviour and properties of these entities.

For example in a car you would look for hp, fuel capacity, etc.

In fruits and vegetables you would look for something different like water content, is it sweet or sour etc.

```
A class is a collection of objects because a collection of objects models a class.In a 
real world sense, you would know how to create fruits by defining a class. You would look 
at fruits and then think hmmmm.. What sort of class should I create for this.
```

**As for the second definition , it's programming specific and is pretty much it itself understandable.**

Hope you get my point. :)

Comment: this is just perfect :)

Answer (score 3):

When your program is running, various objects exist.  Those objects belong to classes.  The code for a class constitutes a description of what it means for an object to belong to a class.

So yes, a class is absolutely a categorisation of objects, or a collection of objects.  When the program is not running, every class is empty - that is, there are no objects of that class.  When the program starts, some objects get created, in some classes.  There will still be some classes for which no objects have yet been created.  Those classes can be thought of as "empty categories".

The thing is that a definition of a class is very detailed.  It specifies what fields an object has.  It specifies what functionality an object has.  But it is still categorising objects - that is, defining some subset of the available objects, and saying "these objects belong to this class".

So both of the definitions of "class" that you have provided are technically correct.  The second definition is far more useful, because it talks about what things we are likely to find in a class - that is, field declarations and method code.

Answer (score 2):

A type is (most generally) defined as a set of possible values, and a class is a type.

But while a class is (in the general sense) a set of *possible* objects, it is not *just* that set.  There is more to it than that.  A class *also* defines representations and behaviours for those objects, and typing relationships with other classes.

So "a class is a set of objects" is a bad definition, but it is still a valid statement.  (And I suspect that if you read the context carefully, you will find that it wasn't given as a definition.)

---

The other thing to beware of is whether you are using "class" / "object" / "type" / "value" in the general sense, or in the context of Java or some other specific programming language.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, **Class is used to define the characteristics of an objects it  will have. A class is used only as a template, or a blueprint**. For instance, for all the persons in your address book, you may say they all will have:

Person:
   - first name 
   - last name 
   - phone number 
   - address

Etc.

An address may have:

Address:
    - street name
    - door number
    - city 
    - zip code 
    - country

In Object Oriented programming we are creating programs using building blocks.

i.e., "enitity(things)" that exists in the real world, these real world things are called objects.
hence it is object oriented

For instance, if you're creating a Address Book program, you may define the following objects:

person, address, phone

Among many, many others. Those would be real life objects, and you describe your program in terms of these abstractions.

With that in mind you can start describing some concepts.

And so on. As you can notice, a class me be defined in terms of other classes, for instance, in this context, a person has one address.

An Object is a particular instance of a given class. When you add an entry to your address book, you create an object and fill in the attributes.

onePerson  ofType Person is (
     - first name = "James"
     - last name = "Blunt" 
     - phone number = "91 58 11 11"
     - address = anAddress ofType Address (
                     - street name = "13the Street" 
                     - door number = 32
                     - city   = "D.F." 
                     - zip code = 23423
                     - country = "Indonesia"
                 ) 
  )

So, this object a class instance with data. Other entry in the address book are other objects with different data.

That shows the difference between class and objects.

Comment: +1 for "Class is used to define the characteristics an objects it will have"

Answer (score 0):

Yes
Class is simply not collection of objects
It means much more
May be that definition is for basic learner don't know even OOP concepts.
Even though nobody has right to change the definition.
I don't this in an answer
Its just my view

Answer (score 0):

Usually class describes objects' attributes and behaviour. I think, the definition "...is collection objects" is not enough. It cannot be a collection, because class is only like a sheet of attributes and behaviour of objects, so it is only an information how to objects deal in your program and what they mean.

Answer (score 0):

Class is a template or mould using which objects are created.